# Python task in scale set agent

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-vm-scale-set

I'm just porting an azure pipeline from Microsoft-hosted agents to [scale set agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops) (due to hardware requirements) and I'm struggling with installing python as scale set agents seem to be more like self hosted agents.

The (old) pipeline starts like this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
  - job: Demo
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.8'
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.8'
```

Just porting this to the new pipeline which is using the scale set pool (using the Ubuntu LTS VM image) results the error message:

```
##[error]Version spec 3.8 for architecture x64 did not match any version in Agent.ToolsDirectory.
```

The link below the message points to a guide [how to configure a self-hosted agent to use this task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version?view=azure-devops#remarks) which tells me, that all files need to be present in the tools cache directory.
But this would require to create a new image as base for the scale set.
Or to download and run the [corresponding github action](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/actions/python-versions/main/versions-manifest.json) before using this task, which fails with an `error while loading shared libraries`.

Having a look in the [code of this task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/UsePythonVersionV0/installpythonversion.ts) shows me, that it's meant to download all of its requirements. But based on this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13319#issuecomment-1059716779) this only is available starting with version 0.202.0 and it's version 0.200.0 being used in the pipeline.

So the base question is:

- how to use this task on scale set agents ?

Additionally:

- how to force the use of a specific task version?
- how to install the required files in the tools cache directory?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is create a custom vm and then use a deployment script to specify the version of python.

Refer this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/deploying-applications-to-azure-vm-scale-sets/) by Atul Malaviya for Indepth explanation on this process.

Also, you will have to delete the vm after ti is created.